# How to fix error TS2339 - property does not exist on 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, typescript-generics

When I press the "next" button, which triggers the code below, the desired action is performed (scrolling to my  element if needed).

But this error apears:  `error TS2339: Property 'scrollIntoViewIfNeeded' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`  and i can't build my project.

```
const h3Title = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null)
```

```
function nextStep(
  currentStep.value++;
  
  if (h3Title.value) {
    h3Title.value.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded({behavior: "smooth", block: "start"})
  }
```

Comment: [`scrollIntoViewIfNeeded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) is a **non-standard proprietary variation** of `scrollIntoView`. Why do you need this specifically and not `scrollIntoView`, which *is* available on `HTMLElement`?

Comment: i just like the behaviour that prevents the scroll as long as the targeted element is in view

Answer (score 4):

I think `h3Title.value.scrollIntoView({block: "nearest"})` would achieve what you want (no scrolling if element is already in view) using the standard scrollIntoView property.

If you really want typescript to recognize the non-standard scrollIntoViewIfNeeded property you can add it to the HTMLElement interface (or make new interface extending HTMLElement):

```js
// global.d.ts
interface HTMLElement {
  scrollIntoViewIfNeeded?: any;
}
```

Alternatively: cast `h3Title.value` as type `any`

```js
(h3Title.value as any).scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()
```